# Running Codename One app in Xcode Simulator - problems

Tags: xcode, codenameone, simulator

Running my CN1 app in the Xcode simulator (to make 6.5" screenshots) I run into problems.
By the way, my app runs fine in the CN1 simulator and on (iOS) devices, also when the app is run from Xcode on a device via a cable connection (for profiling).
I am using macOS Big Sur 11.4 and Xcode 12.5.

Steps:

1. generate a CN1 iOS debug server build with sources included
2. download & unpack the sources, and open the .xcworkspace file in the dist folder with Xcode
3. build the project

This gives 2 purple issues: UI API called from background thread

-[UIViewController view]

-[UIView bounds]

must be used from main thread only.

Below is the extra information on the first issue:

```
Thread 5
#0 0x0000000102e4d1f7 in Java_com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation_getDisplayWidthImpl at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.m:1234
#1 0x000000010307e684 in com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSNative_getDisplayWidth__ at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/IOSNative.m:375
#2 0x0000000103092084 in com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSNative_getDisplayWidth___R_int at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/IOSNative.m:8229
#3 0x0000000102e65184 in com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation_getDisplayWidth___R_int at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation.m:1337
#4 0x0000000102e65c64 in virtual_com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation_getDisplayWidth___R_int at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation.m:16729
#5 0x0000000102e94c24 in com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation_convertToPixels___int_boolean_R_int at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation.m:8585
#6 0x0000000102ddacc4 in virtual_com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneImplementation_convertToPixels___int_boolean_R_int at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneImplementation.m:14619
#7 0x00000001028c0f4c in com_codename1_ui_Display_convertToPixels___float_R_int at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_ui_Display.m:5746
#8 0x00000001029515c4 in com_codename1_ui_plaf_UIManager_resetThemeProps___java_util_Hashtable at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_ui_plaf_UIManager.m:692
#9 0x0000000102950a2c in com_codename1_ui_plaf_UIManager___INIT____ at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_ui_plaf_UIManager.m:288
#10 0x00000001029657b0 in com_codename1_ui_plaf_UIManager_getInstance___R_com_codename1_ui_plaf_UIManager at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_ui_plaf_UIManager.m:308
#11 0x00000001028ab188 in com_codename1_ui_Display_mainEDTLoop__ at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_ui_Display.m:2199
#12 0x0000000102e0bfdc in com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper_run__ at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.m:467
#13 0x0000000102d0e558 in virtual_java_lang_Runnable_run__ at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/java_lang_Runnable.m:60
#14 0x0000000102c5bea8 in com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread_run__ at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.m:384
#15 0x0000000102d0e558 in virtual_java_lang_Runnable_run__ at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/java_lang_Runnable.m:60
#16 0x0000000102bc70c4 in java_lang_Thread_runImpl___long at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/java_lang_Thread.m:254
#17 0x0000000102b5fee4 in threadRunner at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/nativeMethods.m:1337
#18 0x00000001bca3ec8c in _pthread_start
```

My understanding is that is has to do with calling getDisplayWidth() off the main thread. I checked my own calls and as far as I can tell I only call this function on the EDT.

**Running the app anyway** gives build succeeded, then a lot of warnings ('cyclone' is not a recognized processor for this target (ignoring processor)), and finally a runtime error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, stack trace below. My app shows a splash screen, then initializes fine, and crashes after that, before the main screen is shown. Stack trace:

```
Thread 2 Queue : com.apple.opengl.cvmDoWork (serial)
#0 0x00000001a88848b0 in cvmsServerElementBuild ()
#1 0x00000001a8880cd0 in cvms_element_build_from_source ()
#2 0x00000001a8877680 in cvm_deferred_build_modular(void*) ()
#3 0x0000000105d55884 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#4 0x0000000105d5c8dc in _dispatch_lane_serial_drain ()
#5 0x0000000105d5d58c in _dispatch_lane_invoke ()
#6 0x0000000105d693e4 in _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread ()
#7 0x00000001bca3b028 in _pthread_wqthread ()
Enqueued from com.apple.main-thread (Thread 1) Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0 0x0000000105d59570 in _dispatch_async_f_slow ()
#1 0x0000000107da9a84 in gleSetVPTransformFuncAll ()
#2 0x0000000107da4d24 in gleLLVMVecPrimMultiRender ()
#3 0x0000000107d4651c in glDrawArrays_IMM_ES2Exec ()
#4 0x0000000104f717f4 in -[DrawString execute] at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/DrawString.m:250
#5 0x0000000104621128 in -[ExecutableOp executeWithClipping] at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/ExecutableOp.m:60
#6 0x0000000104a563a4 in -[CodenameOne_GLViewController drawFrame:] at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.m:2601
#7 0x0000000104a56f5c in __61-[CodenameOne_GLViewController flushBuffer:x:y:width:height:]_block_invoke at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.m:2872
#8 0x0000000105d55884 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#9 0x0000000105d64f8c in _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke ()
#10 0x0000000105d55884 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#11 0x0000000105d63f84 in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF ()
#12 0x0000000180365d1c in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ ()
#13 0x000000018036025c in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#14 0x000000018035f3bc in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#15 0x000000018afdd70c in GSEventRunModal ()
#16 0x00000001843f03d0 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#17 0x00000001843f51ac in UIApplicationMain ()
#18 0x0000000104c832fc in com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSNative_initVM__ at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/IOSNative.m:348
#19 0x0000000104a694dc in com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation_postInit__ at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_impl_ios_IOSImplementation.m:1262
#20 0x00000001049df89c in virtual_com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneImplementation_postInit__ at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneImplementation.m:14664
#21 0x00000001044a6c20 in com_codename1_ui_Display_init___java_lang_Object at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_codename1_ui_Display.m:1273
#22 0x00000001046122ec in com_xx_yy_MainStub_main___java_lang_String_1ARRAY at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_xx_yy_MainStub.m:282
#23 0x0000000104612348 in main at /Users/MyName/Documents/Xcode/MyApp/dist/Main-src/com_xx_yy_MainStub.m:291
#24 0x0000000180224554 in start ()
```

By accident I found out that it is **possible to run the app in the Xcode simulator anyway**. After the crash above, stop running the app in Xcode. The simulator then shows the "desktop", with on page 2 an icon of my app. When I click that the app runs successfully!

However, it is very slow and the animations are far from fluent. On top of that, the app hangs frequently in different situations, sometimes after seconds, sometimes after many minutes. The UI does not respond anymore but for instance a clock on screen keeps running. No stack trace is available in these cases.

Any tips on how to properly run a CN1 app in Xcode simulator are appreciated. Is it possible that there is relevant CN1 code that should be updated?

Comment: Thanks, we're looking into this and will get back to you

Comment: What platform are you using? Is this an M1 mac?

Comment: Yes, a 2020 MacBook Air with Apple M1 chip.

Comment: Do you think it is safe to release my app now or should I wait for this?

Comment: It's safe. It's something related to the M1. We were able to reproduce this there, it's specific to the air simulator.